# Create divider View not display well in android

Tags: android, android-layout, background-color

I am creating one Layout and in that I am putting divider via `View`. But Both Divider is not looking same. which have all property same.

**Take a close look at screenshot :**

[image]

The First one looked well as I want. But the second one is thin as you can close look.

**Code :**

```
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_security_currentRole"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/normal_margin8"
                android:text="@string/security_current_role"
                android:textColor="#DE000000"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize14" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_currentRole"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_security_currentRole"
                android:background="#61000000" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view_currentRole"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/normal_margin8"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/normal_margin8"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/normal_margin5"
                android:text="@string/security_user"
                android:textColor="#8A000000"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize14" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_upgraderole"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view_currentRole"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/normal_margin8"
                android:text="@string/security_upgrade_role"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize14"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_viewpassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_upgraderole"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/normal_margin8"
                android:text="@string/password"
                android:textColor="#DE000000"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize14" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_viewpassword"
                android:background="#61000000" />
```

If any one know what about that it can tell me.

Any Help be Highly Appreciated.

Comment: Within screen shot i can't see any difference... could you provide me with more detail(code)...

Comment: @Jayamurugan see the ScreenShot the first divider is `clean` and second divider is medium compare to `first one`. I have already posted the code in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a separate layout with the view you want and include it in the places where ever you need...I think this solution would help you...

Comment: I can't use that way because i am using native Xamarin. and sometime it can' t find `<include>` that's why I am creating this way.

Answer (score 2):

I am agree with @Ironman that `Textview` is for displaying `Text`. You can check this:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"/>
```

Comment: Thnx for understanding me. What I say is when I am using `View` for both divider (see the Image in the Question) why they both are display slide difference when I am applying same property to it. ??

Comment: would you please test it mobile device not emulator or another device if you are already used device, cause it's impossible that same code behaving different way.

Comment: got the answer see my ansswer and Thnx for your valuable time and Knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Textview` instead of `View`. Using textview gives same divider as view.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_security_currentRole"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/normal_margin8"
    android:text="@string/security_current_role"
    android:textColor="#DE000000"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize14" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/view_currentRole"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_security_currentRole"
    android:background="#61000000" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view_currentRole"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/normal_margin8"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/normal_margin8"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/normal_margin5"
    android:text="@string/security_user"
    android:textColor="#8A000000"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize14" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_upgraderole"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view_currentRole"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/normal_margin8"
    android:text="@string/security_upgrade_role"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize14"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_viewpassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_upgraderole"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/normal_margin8"
    android:text="@string/password"
    android:textColor="#DE000000"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize14" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/view_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_viewpassword"
    android:background="#61000000" />
```

I've just replaced `<View>` by `<Textview>`

Comment: it is bad idea to set `divider` via `TextView`.

Comment: Why? Can you explain me because I always prefer textview. From now onwards I'll use `View` as a divider

Comment: because simply `TextView` is for `Text` and for the `divider` there are other widget like `View`.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of try like

**1.** Clean the Project and Rebuild it

**2.** Restart The Studio.

**3.** Restart the whole System

nothing is work well.

Finally `Uninstall` the App and `reinstall` is work for me.